# What's the meaning of BIT() in this linux kernel macro?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, macros

I was browsing the Linux kernel code and in the [file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/410feb75de245664d66bc05ab2e2412751d10acf/include/linux/hid.h) `hid.h`, the `HID_QUIRK_ALWAYS_POLL` macro is defined as:

```
#define HID_QUIRK_ALWAYS_POLL   BIT(10)
```

What is the meaning of `BIT(10)`? I am not really familiar with `C` but from what I know (and researched) there is no such bit manipulation function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

looks like you can find the answer inside the first header file included, i.e. [bitops.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/410feb75de245664d66bc05ab2e2412751d10acf/include/linux/bitops.h)!

```
#define BIT(nr) (1UL << (nr))
```

i.e. `BIT` defines a bit mask for the specified bit number from 0 (least significant, or rightmost bit) to whatever fits into an unsigned long.
So `BIT(10)` should evaluate to the numeric value of 1024 (which is `1 << 10`).

Answer (score 5):

BIT is a macro defined in `include/linux/bitops.h` in the kernel tree:

```
#define BIT(nr)         (1UL << (nr))
```

So BIT(10) is basically an unsigned long with tenth bit set.

Answer (score 0):

The `BIT` macro shifts the value `1` left by the value given to it, so `BIT(10)` == `(1 << (10))`. It can be used to get a specific boolean value from a bit field.

Comment: The other answer is probably better because it specifies the type of the value, I only went for the general idea.